# To separate the directory string from a variable in cmd

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to split up the directory value stored in a variable.

Suppose for example if I assign directory path(with double quotes)

**"C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"** to a variable **a**.
I would like to split the last part of the variable **TeamViewer.exe** to one variable **b** and what ever before that to **c**.

For the note

- The value that I assign to **c** may vary depending upon the location of the file I choose.
- The directory path is not predefined I will make it user defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support. I used your idea of removing quotes but not in the line `Set a="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"` but in the next line `For %%A in ("%a%") do (` and it gives me the result I expected. I am changing in the next line because as I told the path I am getting is user defined and the path comes with quotes by default and I cannot avoid the quotes in previous line.

The final sample coding is as below and it works like a charm. Thank you!!

```
@echo off
Set a="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe" 
For %%A in (%a%) do (
    Set c=%%~dpA
    Set b=%%~nxA
)
echo.Folder is: %c%
echo.Name is: %b%
```

Comment: Finally you post an answer to your own question. Great!!!

Answer (score 1):

Being **a** the variable with the full path, you can do this:

```
@echo off
Set a="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe" 
For %%A in ("%a%") do (
    Set c=%%~dpA
    Set b=%%~nxA
)
echo.Folder is: %c%
echo.Name is: %b%
```

Answered with the help of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667026/meaning-of-dpa

Comment: This gives `b=Teamviewer.exe" "` and `c=path from where the batch file is run\TeamViewer`. Remove the quotes from your set command, line 2.

Comment: Hi @Tyler is it possible to get `b=Teamviewer.exe`(without quotes) and **c** to return the path that I give to a i.e the result I want is **c=C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\                               b=TeamViewer.exe**

Comment: @Dragonborn, replace `Set a="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"` with `Set a=C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe` (remove the quotes)

Comment: Hi @Tyler see my below answer. I used your idea of removing quotes in different way and I got what I wished for..